# How to use aggregate in mongoosejs with this example

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, nosql, aggregation-framework

I am here to ask a question about mongo aggregate function to achieve this example.

**Scenario**

I have 3 Mongo Schema i.e House, family and educations which as :

```
House: {
_id: ObjectId,
state: Number,
houseNumber: Number
}

Family: {
    _id: ObjectId,
    houseId: ObjectId,//ref: house
    name: String,
    gender: String
}

Education: {
    _id: ObjectId,
    familyId: ObjectId,//ref: Family
    level: String, //might be one of ["primary","secondary","higher_secondary"]
}
```

**Expected Output:**

```
{
    state1: {
        primary: {
            male: 3,
            female: 4   
        },
        secondary: {
            male: 4,
            female: 8
        }
    },
    state2: {
        primary: {
            male: 5,
            female: 4   
        },
        secondary: {
            male: 4,
            female: 6
        }
    }
}
```

I want to group all the education level by gender and then ward.

**What I did:**

I am newbie in mongo world and recently shifted from sql to no-sql. I had done this:

```
let edu = await Education.find({level: "primary"}).populate({
      path: "family",
      match: {gender: "male"},
      select: "house",
      populate: {
        path: "house",
        match: {state: 1},
        select: "_id"
      }
    });
let count = (await edu.filter(each => !isEmpty(each.family) && !isEmpty(each.family.house)).length) || 0;
```

By doing this I get count of male member who has studied primary from state 1. but I cannot afford to call this function one by one for each data.

As requestd the sample data are:

```
house = [
  {
    _id: AA1,
    state: 1,
    houseNumber: 101
  },
  {
    _id: AA2,
    state: 1,
    houseNumber: 102
  },
  {
    _id: AA3,
    state: 2,
    houseNumber: 201
  }
];

family = [
  {
    _id: BB1,
    houseId: AA1, //ref: house
    name: "John",
    gender: "male"
  },
  {
    _id: BB2,
    houseId: AA1, //ref: house
    name: "Solena",
    gender: "female"
  },
  {
    _id: BB3,
    houseId: AA2, //ref: house
    name: "Efrain",
    gender: "male"
  },
  {
    _id: BB4,
    houseId: AA3, //ref: house
    name: "Naruto",
    gender: "male"
  }
];


education = [
  {
    _id: CC1,
    familyId: AA1, //ref: Family
    level: "primary"
  },
  {
    _id: CC2,
    familyId: AA2, //ref: Family
    level: "secondary"
  },
  {
    _id: CC3,
    familyId: AA3, //ref: Family
    level: "primary"
  },
  {
    _id: CC4,
    familyId: AA4, //ref: Family
    level: "secondary"
  }
];
```

P.S expected output is not relevant output to the sample data. And ObjectId has been replaced with some unique reference.

Any lead from here guyz?

Comment: can you give example of which data store into these collections? or send sample of it

Comment: Can you please put a small data set in your question

Comment: In your House document there is no state field, can you edit your question?

Comment: Thank you so much ! I had added some sample data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use below aggregation query in 4.x version.

Query the family collection and join to education collection to get the level followed by join to house collection to get the state.

Once you have all the data group by state, level and gender to count all the matches followed by other groups for formatting result. Last stage to promote the aggregated result into its own document.

Last two groups formatting the results from previous stage into named key value document. First group to format the results into gender and count grouped by state. Second group to format the previously combined gender and count with education key.

Finally replace root stage to format the combined gender, count and education doc with state key.

Also added output after each stage for clarity.

```
db.family.aggregate(
[
  {"$lookup":{
    "from":"education",
    "localField":"_id",
    "foreignField":"familyId",
    "as":"education"
  }},
  {"$unwind":"$education"},
  {"$lookup":{
    "from":"house",
    "localField":"houseId",
    "foreignField":"_id",
    "as":"state"
  }},
  {"$unwind":"$state"},
  {"$group":{
    "_id":{
      "state":"$state.state",
      "education":"$education.level",
      "gender":"$gender"
    },
    "count":{"$sum":1}
  }},//{"_id":{"state" :1,"education" :"secondary","gender":"female"},"count":1}
  {"$group":{
    "_id":{"state":"$_id.state","education":"$_id.education"},
    "gandc":{"$mergeObjects":{"$arrayToObject":[[["$_id.gender","$count"]]]}}
  }},//{"_id":{"state":1,"education":"primary"},"gandc":{"male":2}}
  {"$group":{
    "_id":"$_id.state",
    "egandc":{"$mergeObjects":{"$arrayToObject":[[["$_id.education","$gandc"]]]}}
  }},//{"_id":1,"egandc":{"primary":{"male":2},"secondary":{"female":1}}}
  {"$replaceRoot":{"newRoot":{"$arrayToObject":[[[{"$toString":"$_id"},"$egandc"]]]}}} ])
])
//{"1":{"primary":{"male" : 2 },"secondary":{"female":1}}}
```

Comment: Hello sir. Thank you so much for your work. I have always work on mongoose and I am afraid to ask you how  do i get first variable db ? How to i import and what is the dependency of that to what npm?

Comment: You’re welcome. This is shell query ( can be run as is from mongo cli). For mongoose you can use Family.aggregate(copy the query inside the ()) assuming you have family model defined somewhere. Examples here https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/aggregate.html

Comment: Yea I have done that and mongoose didn't find $mergeObjects ` MongoError: unknown group operator '$mergeObjects'`.

Comment: Looks like you are in old version. You would need 4.x mongo version. Latest version is 4.2. See if you can upgrade. Pleas check mongo server version not mongoose lib version.

Comment: I had upgraded mongo server version and it still says MongoError: unknown group operator '$mergeObjects. I have mongo server version: 4.2, mongoose: 5.9.2 and mongodb driver: 3.5.4

Comment: Thank you so much.. Can i ask you one extra thing here. Please help me out?

What I want is: 
result with only level : primary on education collection

Comment: You’re welcome. You can use $match stage after first unwind to filter level. Something like `{$match:{"education.level": "primary"}}`